# How to use Borel-Cantelli specifically to show that the probability of a simple random walk returning to the origin in finite time is 1?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Suppose we have that $X_i$ are iid random variables with $P(X_i =1) = P(X_i = -1) = 1/2$ and that $X_0 = 0$. Then, we define the simple symmetric random walk to be $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. We define the hitting time as $\tau_{i,j} = min\{n \geq 1 : S_n = j \ |\ S_0 = i\}$. I would like to show that $P(\tau_{0,0} < \infty) = 1$.

Specifically, I would like to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma to show that if I can define some independent sequence of events here, and show that the sum of the events is infinite, then moves of some finite length happen infinitely often, and so I can show that it must return to $0$. However, I am not sure how to define such an indexed event. Could someone give me a hint? Thank you

Comment: I don't think B-C is the way to go about this.

Comment: You should really use the fact that $\{S_n\}$ is a Markov Chain.

Answer (score 1):

My reputation is under 50, hence I cannot add comments to contact the user [jwg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/64062/jwg). So this is the only way to warn that, IMHO, the above solution of [jwg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/64062/jwg) is probably wrong. He states that

> So the events that it reaches $n$ for the first time, and then reaches $0$
>   before $n+1$, are disjoint and independent.

Yes, they are disjoint, which implies that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n) = P(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n) \leq 1$, which contradicts

> The sum of their probabilities is infinite...

Another problem is the independence:

Independence of, say, $A_2$ and $A_6$ would mean that $P(A_2 \cap A_6) = P(A_2) P(A_6)$. However, the left-hand side is zero (since $A_2$ and $A_6$ are disjoint), while the right-hand side is positive (since  $P(A_n)>0$ for all $n$).

It will be exremely enlightening, if [jwg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/64062/jwg) provides a more detailed reasoning. The possibility of proving the posted problem just by Borel-Cantelli makes me very curious, since I have never seen that kind of solution.

Comment: Indeed, disjoint and independent events are rather rare... :-)

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out in comments, there could be good ways of doing this using not Borel-Cantelli, but the properties of either Markov Chains or (I would recommend) martingales, since your random walk is both a Markov chain and a martingale.

However, there is a neat argument which uses the Borel-Cantelli lemma. Suppose that the random walk is at $n$. The probability of reaching $0$ before reaching $n+1$ is $\frac{1}{n+1}$.

For the random walk to go back to $0$, it must reach some maximum $k$, then go back $0$ before ever reaching $k+1$. (Or the same argument by symmetry if it goes to $-1$ before $1$.) So the events that it reaches $n$ for the first time, and then reaches $0$ before $n+1$, are disjoint and independent. The sum of their probabilities is infinite, hence at least one of them must occur with probability $1$.

To see that the probability, when at $n$, of reaching $0$ before $n+1$ is $\frac{1}{n+1}$, you could use a simple martingale argument. If win \$1 for heads and lose \$1 for tails, and stop gambling when you win \$1 or lose \$n, the probability of winning or losing must be such that your expectation is \$0.

One can also see that to remain in a range for ever without ever reaching either of the endpoints has probability $0$. To see this, just consider that there is a positive probability of getting $m$ heads or $m$ tails in a row, where $m$ is the length of the range. If we have infinite tries, we must, with probability $1$, get this sequence eventually.

Comment: "So the events that it reaches n for the first time, and then reaches 0 before n+1, are disjoint and independent" No. (Note that independent and disjoint events, whose probability are not 0 or 1, do not exist.)